# Hide Create Account with Amplify on Flutter using Authenticator UI library

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I have a Flutter app that is using the Amplify Authenticator UI library and I'm trying to find a way to disable or hide the "Create Account" area. Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom `authenticatorBuilder` to the Authenticator widget, which overrides the whole layout, including the Sign In / Create Account headings.

The default options they show in the docs under full UI customization (https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator?platform=flutter#full-ui-customization) is enough to remove it - and you still get the original SignInForm.

```
return Authenticator(
      authenticatorBuilder: (context, state) {
        switch (state.currentStep) {
          case AuthenticatorStep.signIn:
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('My App')),
              body: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    // flutter logo
                    const Center(child: FlutterLogo(size: 100)),
                    // prebuilt sign in form from amplify_authenticator package
                    SignInForm(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          default:
            return null;
        }
      },
      child: ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks #fireproofpenguin that worked perfectly.